# Invalid request URI while adding a video to playlist via youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-api, gdata-api

I have been unable to overcome this error while trying to add a video to my playlist using the youtube gdata python api.

> gdata.service.RequestError: {'status':
>   400, 'body': 'Invalid request URI',
>   'reason': 'Bad Request'}

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048902/youtube-python-api-gdata-service-requesterror) seems to be the same error, but there are no solutions as yet. Any help guys?

```
 import getpass
 import gdata.youtube
 import gdata.youtube.service

 yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()

 # The YouTube API does not currently support HTTPS/SSL access.
 yt_service.ssl = False
 yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
 yt_service.email = #myemail
 yt_service.password = getpass.getpass()
 yt_service.developer_key = #mykey
 yt_service.source = #text
 yt_service.client_id= #text
 yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()

 feed = yt_service.GetYouTubePlaylistFeed(username='default')
 # iterate through the feed as you would with any other
 for entry in feed.entry:
     if (entry.title.text == "test"):
         lst = entry;
         print entry.title.text, entry.id.text

 custom_video_title = 'my test video on my test playlist'  
 custom_video_description = 'this is a test video on my test playlist'  
 video_id = 'Ncakifd_16k'  
 playlist_uri = lst.id.text    

 playlist_video_entry = yt_service.AddPlaylistVideoEntryToPlaylist(playlist_uri, video_id, custom_video_title, custom_video_description)    

 if isinstance(playlist_video_entry, gdata.youtube.YouTubePlaylistVideoEntry):
 print 'Video added'
```

The confounding thing is that updating the playlist works, but adding a video does not.

```
 playlist_entry_id = lst.id.text.split('/')[-1]
 original_playlist_description = lst.description.text
 updated_playlist = yt_service.UpdatePlaylist(playlist_entry_id,'test',original_playlist_description,playlist_private=False)
```

The video_id is not wrong because its the video from the sample code. What am I missing here? Somebody help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gdata seems to use v1 API. So, the relevant documentation is here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieving_a_playlist

This means, your "playlist_uri" should not take the value of "lst.id.text", but should take the "feedLink" element's "href" attribute in order to be used with "AddPlaylistVideoEntryToPlaylist"

Even if you happen to use v2 API, you should take the URI from the "content" element's "src" attribute as explained in the documentation, you get by substituting 2.0, in the above URL! (SO doesn't allow me to put two hyperlinks because i don't have enough reputations! :))